# How many people were seriously injured during the Catalan independence referendum?

Tags: statistics, catalonia, spain, ngos

There are currently a lot of quotes about "[hundreds of injured people](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-41461032)" during the Catalan independence referendum but they all come from a potentially biased source, (Catalan government), and don't mention the *types* of injuries sustained by the protesters.

Are there detailed statistics somewhere from a less partial source on how many people were *seriously* injured and required medical attention?

A lot of the arguments against the Spanish government rest upon the unreasonable use of violence, but it's hard to judge the scale of this violence objectively.

Note: this is on-topic for Politics.SE because the issue has become a core point of discussion in the current Catalonian independence movement.

Comment: As far as I know, no one is disputing the numbers given by the Catalan emergency officials. Not even the Spanish government. Why do you? Also, I  doubt you'll get _detailed statistics_ for such a recent event.

Comment: @yannis I couldn't find any statistics on what kinds of injuries those were. E.g. light bruises vs. broken bones and concussions.

Comment: I've voted to close this as off topic because it isn't about politics, the political process, or politicians. If it were rephrased to evaluate the decision processes that led to injuries, or the decision process to accept injuries, it would be on topic.

Comment: this is not off topic, as has been politicized by both sides. Fake facebook accounts (russia again?) have mixed violent images from years ago, and catalonian politicians have been accused of instruct hospitals on count  any urgency on this day as originated by police violence.

Comment: https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2629/7717 seems like a better place to argue whether or not this question is on topic than in the body of the question itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If [this Le Monde article](http://www.lemonde.fr/europe/article/2017/10/02/recit-d-une-journee-de-vote-et-d-affrontements-en-catalogne_5194595_3214.html) is anything to go by, 844 were injured, of which 128 were hospitalized and two were seriously injured according to the Catalan authorities.

Comment: To complete the report, the two seriously injured are a man who was hit in the eye with a rubber ball and a man who suffered a heart attack when the police entered a polling station.

Comment: This puts the headlines in a much better and less dramatic perspective.