# What is the opinion of non-Catalan Spanish citizens regarding the use of force to subdue the Catalan independence?

Tags: public-opinion, catalonia, spain

Recently there have been a lot of news regarding the police involvement in the Catalan independence referendum, where [2 people were seriously injured](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/25082/how-many-people-were-seriously-injured-during-the-catalan-independence-referendu). Have there been any polls in "mainland" Spain regarding the recent intervention and the general question of using force to subdue the secession movement?

I presume most non-Catalans don't support the secession in the first place, but it's not clear if they support harsh measures from the government in Madrid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's been indeed polls about it. I could find one in the Spanish digital newspapers [El Español](https://www.elespanol.com/) and the results are a bit shocking: as many Spanish people agree and do not agree with the use of force. However, in Catalonia there are 8 times more people against it. And, in fact, if you substract Catalan people from the Spanish overall, there is a 50% of people in favour of them, while less than 40% are not.

Numbers come from a poll on 800 people: 400 living in Catalonia and 400 living somewhere else in Spain.

From [*El 46% de los españoles rechaza las cargas policiales del 1-O y el 44% las aprueba*](https://www.elespanol.com/espana/20171005/251975622_0.html), that is: *46% of Spanish people are against police charges from 1-O and 44% agree with them*.

[image]

Blocks:

- *Total España*: overall Spain
- *Reside fuera de Cataluña*: living outside Catalonia
- *Reside en Cataluña*: living in Catalonia

Bars:

- Green-ish: agrees
- Pink-ish: does not agree
- Blue: do not know / do not want to answer

---

Going through all the results on the poll [Un 61% de españoles, pero sólo el 30% de catalanes, "aprueba" el mensaje del Rey](https://www.elespanol.com/espana/politica/20171005/251975092_0.html) that is, *61% of Spanish, and just 30% of Catalans, "agree" with King's message* reveal other interesting details, such as 61% of Catalans seeing King's message as something that has weakened his position, while less than 30% thinks it got stronger.

Comment: I guess it is easy to imagine the feeling of Catalans when half of Spanish agree on police beating them :O

Comment: `when half of Spanish agree on police fighting people who prevents the police from doing their jobs`. FTFY, you are welcome. Excessive or not (there is a judicial inquiry in progresss), the fighting took place when people tried to oppose the police, it is not as if the police were hitting people at random...

Comment: @SJuan76 I don't think images like these are far away from _hitting people at random_: [Tensión en el instituto Pau Claris de Barcelona](https://elpais.com/elpais/2017/10/01/videos/1506853694_401661.html)

Comment: ??? The video shows only people who were opposing the action of the police. You could argue if the level of violence was justified or not (as I did mention there is an ongoing judicial inquiry), but certainly the people in the video were not "random people".

Comment: @SJuan76 first of all, I don't need to fix my initial comment, just leave it as your personal opinion. Secondly, downvoting because you don't agree on a comment doesn't seem to fit on SE's philosophy: [_Focus on the content. Not the users. Down-vote poor content, up-vote good content, flag abusive content..._](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/85359/209901).